# what are the differences in IntelliJ vs. eclipse regarding groovy development

Tags: eclipse, groovy, intellij-idea

I am new to IntelliJ coming from Eclipse(mainly Java) and I am trying to find out what Groovy features are included in one IDE that are missing in the other.

**Example:**

- Eclipse shows error in package explorer and in file when package import is incomplete

  ```
  import Specification --> import spock.lang.Specification
  ```
- Eclipse shows package mismatch error in package explorer and in file when package name is incorrect to directory structure.
- IntelliJ highlights class own methods/properties in code completion in bold eclipse does not.

I would like to gather informations about both IDEs regarding groovy support. This is not about which IDE is better but what are the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using idea for groovy development for very long time and its support is great.
Among the little details I know and like:

- Idea spock support permit to:
  -- indent the "given:", "when:", and other "then:" labels which is great.
  -- you can even have then "colorized as other groovy keywords with the spock plugin"
  -- idea also indent recognize the data driven column title as variable for the spec code and indent this tables
  -- and idea also support creation of new specification with the "navigate to test" shortcut. "Ctrl+Shift+T"
- Idea also support logger generated by ats like "@Log"